# why does my neural network coded from scratch results have such a weird loss trend?

Tags: python, neural-network, backpropagation, cross-entropy, mlp

I am developing neural network from scratch. It consists of of the following input > layer1(sigmoid) > layer2 > output(softmax). The basic coding is complete but when I ran it, I obtain a weird loss plot. Also if I ran the code for large iterations I obtain 'nan' in the output. Any help is appreciated. [image: loss]

I spent a bit of time going through the derivations and checking my implementation but cannot spot what the issue is. See my derivations attached, I am interested in the softmax loss and sorry about the writing.
derivations link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VBSO8Ox6U3Vo9FvgT8gKUBZPEEEjzMS_/view?usp=drivesdk

code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import sklearn as sk
from sklearn import preprocessing
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

(x_train,y_train),(x_test,y_test)=mnist.load_data()

n_train = 100
x_train = x_train[0:n_train].reshape(-1,784)/255
y_train0 = y_train[0:n_train].reshape(-1,)
y_train1 = pd.get_dummies(y_train0)
y_train = np.array( y_train1.astype(int) )


nx = 784 #input size (nx,1)
n1 = 20   #neurons in 1st layer
n_class = 10  #neurons in 2nd layer


lambda0 = 0.00  #center loss parameter
alpha =  0.0001  #gradient decent parameter

#layer weights
#The network is simple 
#Input, n1 neurons with sigmoid activation, 10 neurons and softmax output
W1 = 0.001*np.random.rand( n1, nx )
W2 = 0.001*np.random.rand( n_class, n1 )
b2 = 0.001*np.random.rand( n_class,1  )
b1 = 0.001*np.random.rand( n1,1  )
centers = np.random.rand(n_class,1)


def softmax(x):
 
    exp_sum = np.sum( np.exp(x) )
    
    return np.exp(x)/( exp_sum )

def sigmoid(x):
    y = 1/(1+ np.exp(-x) )
    
    return y



def test():
    count = 0
    for t3 in range(0,100):
        
        #forward propagation #Layer 1
        Z1 = np.dot( W1 , x_train[t3]).reshape(-1,1)  
        A1 = sigmoid( Z1 ).reshape(-1,1)         
        #forward propagation #Layer 2
        Z2 = np.dot( W2, A1)  + b2
        Output = softmax(Z2)
        
        
        arg_max =  np.argmax(Output)
        
        if arg_max == np.argmax(y_train[t3:t3+1] ):
            count = count +1
            
    
    print(count/100)        
    

def new_center(x,y0,c0):
    c = np.zeros( (n_class, 1) )
    y = np.argmax(y0, axis=-1) #convert to one column array
    for i in range(n_class):
        indx = np.where(y == i)[0] #choose all points that equal class i
        a1 = np.mean( x[ [indx] ].reshape(-1,n_class)  )
        c[i,:] = a1
        
    return c-c0

iter = 50000
sets = 100
loss_temp = np.zeros(( sets ,1))
loss = []
Zi_vector =  np.zeros(( sets ,n_class))
y_pred_vector = np.zeros(( sets ,n_class))
loss = np.zeros(( iter,1))

print_counter = 0
for t1 in range (0,iter):
    
    for t2 in range(0,sets):
    
        #forward propagation #Layer 1 & 2
        Z1 = np.dot( W1 , x_train[t2:t2+1].T ).reshape(-1,1)  + b1
        A1 = sigmoid( Z1 ).reshape(-1,1)         
        #forward propagation #Layer 2
        Z2 = np.dot( W2, A1)  + b2
        Output = softmax(Z2)


        #back propagation #Layer 2
        dy = Output - y_train[t2:t2+1].T #+ lambda0*(Z2- centers)
        
        dE_dZ2 = dy
        dE_dW2 = dy*A1.T
        dE_db2 = dy
        W2T = W2.T
        
        
        #backpropagation #Layer 1
        dE_dZ2T = np.zeros((n1,1))
        dA1_dZ1 = Z1*(1-Z1) 
        
        for temp1 in range(0,n1):
            dE_dZ2T[temp1] = np.dot( dy.T, W2T[temp1].T )
            
        dE_dZ2T__dA1_dZ1 = dE_dZ2T*dA1_dZ1  
        dE_dW1 = dE_dZ2T__dA1_dZ1 * x_train[t2].T
        
        
        # #For regularization
        # L2_W2 = W2*0.001
        # L2_W1 = W1*0.001
        # L2_b2 = b2*0.001
        # L2_b1 = b1*0.001
        
        #weight update
        W1 = W1 - alpha*(dE_dW1  )               
        W2 = W2 - alpha*( dE_dW2   )
        b2 = b2 - alpha*(dy   )
        b1 = b1 - alpha*( dE_dZ2T__dA1_dZ1   )
        
        
        loss_temp[t2] = (  -np.sum( y_train[t2:t2+1]*np.log10(Output.T) ) )
        

        Zi_vector[t2] = Z2.reshape(-1,)
        y_pred_vector[t2,:] = Output.reshape(-1,n_class)


    #centers = new_center(Zi_vector,y_train, centers)        
        
    loss[t1] = ( np.mean(loss_temp)) 
    loss_temp = np.zeros(( 100 ,1))


    print_counter = print_counter + 1
    if print_counter > 100:
        print(t1) 
        print_counter = 1 

        
test()

plt.plot(loss )
plt.xlabel('iterations')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what fixed it but, I 1) scaled the the inputs into softmax function and 2) rewrote the weight update for W2.

The loss looks as expected [image: Loss].

The loss becomes zero after 10000 iterations also the accuracy becomes 1 which is what I was expecting for an overfitted model trained on few data.

code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import sklearn as sk
from sklearn import preprocessing
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

(x_train,y_train),(x_test,y_test)=mnist.load_data()

n_train = 100
x_train = x_train[0:n_train].reshape(-1,784)/255
y_train0 = y_train[0:n_train].reshape(-1,)
y_train1 = pd.get_dummies(y_train0)
y_train = np.array( y_train1.astype(int) )


nx = 784 #input size (nx,1)
n1 = 20   #neurons in 1st layer
n_class = 10  #neurons in 2nd layer


lambda0 = 0.00  #center loss parameter
alpha =  0.0001  #gradient decent parameter

#layer weights
#The network is simple 
#Input, n1 neurons with sigmoid activation, 10 neurons and softmax output
W1 = 0.001*np.random.rand( n1, nx )
W2 = 0.001*np.random.rand( n_class, n1 )
b2 = 0.001*np.random.rand( n_class,1  )
b1 = 0.001*np.random.rand( n1,1  )
centers = np.random.rand(n_class,1)


def softmax(x):
    xmin = np.min(x)
    xmax = np.max(x)
    b = 100
    a = 1
    xnormalized = (b-a)*(x-xmin)/(0.001 +xmax - xmin) + a
    exp_sum = np.sum( np.exp( xnormalized ) )
    
    return np.exp( xnormalized )/( exp_sum )

def sigmoid(x):
    y = 1/(1+ np.exp(-x) )
    
    return y



def test():
    count = 0
    for t3 in range(0,100):
        
        #forward propagation #Layer 1
        Z1 = np.dot( W1 , x_train[t3]).reshape(-1,1)  
        A1 = sigmoid( Z1 ).reshape(-1,1)         
        #forward propagation #Layer 2
        Z2 = np.dot( W2, A1)  + b2
        Output = softmax(Z2)
        
        
        arg_max =  np.argmax(Output)
        
        if arg_max == np.argmax(y_train[t3:t3+1] ):
            count = count +1
            
    
    print(count/100)        
    

def new_center(x,y0,c0):
    c = np.zeros( (n_class, 1) )
    y = np.argmax(y0, axis=-1) #convert to one column array
    for i in range(n_class):
        indx = np.where(y == i)[0] #choose all points that equal class i
        a1 = np.mean( x[ [indx] ].reshape(-1,n_class)  )
        c[i,:] = a1
        
    return c-c0

iter = 20000
sets = 100
loss_temp = np.zeros(( sets ,1))
loss = []
Zi_vector =  np.zeros(( sets ,n_class))
y_pred_vector = np.zeros(( sets ,n_class))
loss = np.zeros(( iter,1))

print_counter = 0
for t1 in range (0,iter):
    
    for t2 in range(0,sets):
    
        #forward propagation #Layer 1 & 2
        Z1 = np.dot( W1 , x_train[t2:t2+1].T ).reshape(-1,1)  + b1
        A1 = sigmoid( Z1 ).reshape(-1,1)         
        #forward propagation #Layer 2
        Z2 = np.dot( W2, A1)  + b2
        Output = softmax(Z2)


        #back propagation #Layer 2
        dy = Output - y_train[t2:t2+1].T #+ lambda0*(Z2- centers)
        
        dE_dZ2 = dy
        dE_dW2 = dy*A1.T
        dE_db2 = dy
        W2 = W2
        
        
        #backpropagation #Layer 1
        dE_dZ2T = np.zeros((n1,1))
        dA1_dZ1 = Z1*(1-Z1) 
        
        # for temp1 in range(0,n1):
        #     dE_dZ2T[temp1] = np.dot( dy.T, W2[temp1].T )
            
        dE_dZ2T__dA1_dZ1 = np.dot(W2.T, dy) * dA1_dZ1 
        dE_dW1 = dE_dZ2T__dA1_dZ1 * x_train[t2].T
        
        
        # #For regularization
        # L2_W2 = W2*0.001
        # L2_W1 = W1*0.001
        # L2_b2 = b2*0.001
        # L2_b1 = b1*0.001
        
        #weight update
        W1 = W1 - alpha*(dE_dW1  )               
        W2 = W2 - alpha*( dE_dW2   )
        b2 = b2 - alpha*(dy   )
        b1 = b1 - alpha*( dE_dZ2T__dA1_dZ1   )
        
        
        loss_temp[t2] = (  -np.sum( y_train[t2:t2+1]*np.log10(Output.T) ) )
        

        Zi_vector[t2] = Z2.reshape(-1,)
        y_pred_vector[t2,:] = Output.reshape(-1,n_class)


    #centers = new_center(Zi_vector,y_train, centers)        
        
    loss[t1] = ( np.mean(loss_temp)) 
    loss_temp = np.zeros(( 100 ,1))


    print_counter = print_counter + 1
    if print_counter > 100:
        print(t1) 
        print_counter = 1 

        
test()

plt.plot(loss )
plt.xlabel('iterations')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.show()

# plt.scatter( Zi_vector[:,1]  , Zi_vector[:,2] )
# plt.show()
```